# Codeigniter database join with extra variable

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to join two tables but comparison is with external variable, like $ext_user

```
$this->db->join('ec_details2', 'ec_details.user_id = ec_users.user_id','INNER');
```

Instead of `ec_users.user_id` in above code i want to use `$ext_user`, how can i do this like below?

```
$this->db->join('ec_details2', 'ec_details.user_id = $ext_user','INNER');
```

If i do with my 2nd option it will not take $ext_user as variable, but taking as complete string!

Thanks,

Comment: Try like this :
$this->db->join('ec_details2', 'ec_details.user_id ='. $ext_user,'INNER');

Comment: Is $ext_user an ID or is it a table field name?

Comment: @TimBrownlaw, its ID but it will come from form field, means externally

Comment: its ID but it will come from form field, means externally ? Can you explain more

Comment: @SatishShinde, actually i am doing analytics reporting of data which are inside database, user will send some filters and data need to retrieve, so $user_id will be send by user as AJAX form

Answer (score 2):

I think it is about variables will not be expanded when they occur in single quoted strings.

And it work by the double-quoted.

```
$this->db->join('ec_details2', "ec_details.user_id = $ext_user",'INNER');
```